# escpos python libary to print barcode and logo with message

Tags: python-2.7, escpos, posprinter

```
from escpos import printer
import random
printFile = "/dev/usb/lp0"
printer = printer.File(printFile)
printer.set('left')
printer.image('logo.jpg')
printer.text("My Company")
```

## Once below the logo and my company name i need barcode:

```
Epson.barcode('1324354657687','code39',64,2,'','')
```

## problem 1: i need logo to left and My company name in the same line but it prints logo and below logo My company name

## Problem 2 i need my barcode to be code39 it just print the number

how do i solve both the problem, so far i have tried this .

## Coder will live for ever